# Bootstrap modal via ajax and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I load content for modal by ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'p1.html',
      success: function(data){
        $(data).modal();
        alert('success')
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('why not work')
            set_valign_modal() // IMPORTANT - if You do not want to set content of modal boxes in middle in vertical, just remove this function init
        });
```

Quick question, why callback for modal:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e){
```

doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps if you could create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

> why callback for modal

I can think of three possible reasons:

1. `#myModal` isn't the modal or an ancestor of it
2. You don't hook the event until *after* it fires. The `show.bs.modal` event fires **immediately** when you show a modal. So if the modal shows immediately when you call `$(data).modal();`, and you don't hook it until afterward, you've missed it.
3. You never actually add the elements involved in the modal to the DOM

Comment: $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) also do not work - @myModal is in p1.html file and it's a modal

Comment: `$(data).modal();` only creates an instance of `modal` object. `$(data).modal('show');` will trigger `show.bs.modal` event.

Comment: @Michael: I think my #3 is probably closest to the mark, but we really need more information.

Comment: #myModal exist when I check in chrome - it's there :) ... just like when I do not make it throught ajax

Comment: @Michael: But is it there **when the code runs**, as opposed to afterward when you check? Use the debugger, Luke!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a listener on this line:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('why not work')
            set_valign_modal() // IMPORTANT - if You do not want to set content of modal boxes in middle in vertical, just remove this function init
        });
```

This should be set somewhere else, unless you intend to set the callback on the ajax response.

ALSO, this callback will be only called after firing:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

and since in your code you are calling the modal before, it will not fire the callback.

Try this instead:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert('why not work');
});

$('#ajax').on('click',function()
{

    $.ajax({
      url: 'p1.html',
      success: function(data){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

        }
    });
});
```

I should also say that it will only work in the case that data == '#myModal'

here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/262/)

Comment: it doesn't work ... modal works fine if it's in index.html, but I want to load it via ajax so I move it to p1.html ... and my script show modal but all callbacks doesn't work

Comment: You could even add a timeout if you want the callback code to be executed after the modal view is fully loaded.

Comment: $('#myModal').on('shown.bs - is called when modal if fully loaded ... But right now I see in network, that p1.html was loaded, but no callbacks work #myModal do not exist in DOM ... i don't understand :)

Comment: As you can see in my fiddle,  the modal html must exist in your html

Comment: by "add via ajax" you mean $('body').append("modal html...");??

Comment: $(data).modal().on('shown.bs.modal', function(){ alert('') } works - but $(data).modal() and then $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){ alert('') } does not ... so there must be some time that modal is not there ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'p1.html',
              success: function(data){

               //## set instance of plugin in variable    
               var $m=$(data).modal(); 

               //and then add event using variable 
               $m.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    alert('why not work')
                    set_valign_modal() // IMPORTANT - if You do not want to set content of modal boxes in middle in vertical, just remove this function init
                });
            }
        });
    })
```